Why can't I access path variable inside IIFE?
When I write const path = require('path') outside the IIFE function I can't access it inside, but when I write it inside the function I am able to access it. Can anyone explain why is this happening?
Can't access in this case:
const path = require('path')

(async (directory) => {
    console.log(await fs.readdir(directory))
    fs.rename(path.join(__dirname, 'files'), path.join(__dirname, "randomFiles"))
})(__dirname)

Can access in this case:
(async (directory) => {
    const path = require('path')
    console.log(await fs.readdir(directory))
    fs.rename(path.join(__dirname, 'files'), path.join(__dirname, "randomFiles"))
})(__dirname)

Why?
I was expecting it to work on both cases.

The adjacent lines are being interpreted by JS as one statement. Use semi-colons to terminate your statements and you won't have that problem.
As Brendan Eich once wrote:

"The moral of this story: ASI is (formally speaking) a syntactic error correction procedure. If you start to code as if it were a universal significant-newline rule, you will get into trouble."

You should also add in your import for fs to use its promises API.
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');

(async (directory) => {
    console.log(await fs.readdir(directory));
    fs.rename(path.join(__dirname, 'path.js'), path.join(__dirname, "randomFiles"));
})(__dirname);

